# Why does (true ? false ? '1' : '2' : '3') return 2?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

What is the logic that returns `2` from the following JavaScript?

```
true ? false ? '1' : '2' : '3'
```

Comment: Do you understand why `true ? '1' : '2'` would return `'1'`?

Comment: Same as `true ? (false ? '1' : '2') : '3'`, since the ternary operator associates to the right

Answer (score 1):

Look up operator [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Since the ternary operator is **right - associative**, the above expression gets parsed to this:

```
true ? (false ? '1' : '2') : '3'
```

**[Right - to - left associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Associativity)** means the operator at the most right is executed first.

In our case the right - most ternary operator is the **inner** one, and is thus executed first.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

1. If true, then the result is false. `true ? false`
2. If false, then the result is 1. `false ? '1'`
3. Else, the result is 2. `: '2'`
4. At the end, im guessing this compiles because it groups the statement like this: `true ? (false ? '1' : '2') : '3'`. So if you turn the first `true` into a `false`, it should return 3.

Hope that helps... if you still dont understand please ask!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add here, this is how the expression would translate with an `if-else` statement

```
// Translated:
if (true) {
  if (false) {
    console.log(1)
  }
  else {
    console.log(2)
  } 
} else {
  console.log(3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

?: is [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

So your code:

```
var x = true ? false ? '1' : '2' : '3'
```

is the shorthand version of:

```
var x;

if(true){
    if(false){
        x = '1';
    }else{
        x = '2'; // <= You will be here.
    }
}else {
    x = 3;
}
```